# Using a comparator with generics

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I am trying to use a generic method to sort an array. I am receiving an error on `Lab6Sort(octArr);` that says *classname* cannot be applied to Shape[].

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shape[] octArr = new Shape[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        octArr[i] = new L6MPerRegOct(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) / 10);
    }

    Lab6Sort(octArr);
}
.
.
 public static <AnyType> void Lab6Sort (AnyType [] arr, Comparator<? super AnyType> cmp)
```

It seems that I need a second argument, but I am unsure what this should be.

Here is the complete code:

```
public class L6MPerRegOct extends Shape {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape[] octArr = new Shape[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            octArr[i] = new L6MPerRegOct(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) / 10);
        }

        Lab6Sort(octArr);

    }

    private double sideLength;

    public L6MPerRegOct(double len){
        sideLength = len;
    }

    public double area(){
        return 2 * sideLength*sideLength * (1 + Math.sqrt(2));
    }
    public static <AnyType> void Lab6Sort (AnyType [] arr, Comparator<? super AnyType> cmp)
    {
        int j, minIndex, n = arr.length;
        AnyType temp;

        for ( int index = 0; index < n - 1; index++ ) {
            minIndex = index;

            for (j = index + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (cmp.compare(arr[index], arr[minIndex]) < 0)
                    minIndex = j;
            }

            if (minIndex != index) {
                temp = arr[index];

                arr[index] = arr[minIndex];

                arr[minIndex] = temp;
        }
    }

public abstract class Shape implements Comparable<Shape>
{
    public abstract double area( );
    public abstract double perimeter( );

    public int compareTo( Shape rhs )
    {
        double diff = area( ) - rhs.area( );
        if( diff == 0 )
            return 0;
        else if( diff < 0 )
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    public double semiperimeter( )
    {
        return perimeter( ) / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: The example needs to show the relationship between `AnyType` and `Shape`. I know it can be guessed, but the OP is apparently new to stackoverflow, and it will bode them well to ask elaborate questions that can be answered by experts without too much back-and-fort. This will be important when they want to ask more complex questions.

Comment: @MiserableVariable he uses `AnyType` as the Generic `T`, so it's fine.

Comment: That is actually true @radoh, I withdraw my comment re. `AnyType`.

Comment: @brso05 I believe the problem the other gentlemen have, is that in ideal world, you'd want to copy&paste the code example into your IDE, and see for yourself if it works/doesn't. You'd receive a compilation error for the given example in this question, since the `L6MPerRegOct` type is undefined.

Comment: My original comment was driven by the thought that there is a rather fundamental mistake, which would have been solved by OP if they had bothered to come up with an SCCE. On the other hand, they could have been indeed confused how to define the comparator, but if they worked on a more specific sample code they might have been able to phrase the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it an instance of a `Comparator`, e.g.

```
Lab6Sort(octArr, new Comparator<Shape>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Shape o1, Shape o2) {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Or define the Comparator in a separate class, if you want to reuse it

```
public class ShapeComparator implements Comparator<Shape> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Shape o1, Shape o2) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ShapeComparator implements Comparator<Shape> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Shape o1, Shape o2) {

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included an explanation along with the code.